# Excel Userform "Apply" button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `userform` populated with command buttons: the clicked button determines which macro to call, and each button hides the form, which allows the code in the regular module to proceed.

What's the best way to implement an "Apply" button, (e.g, to execute a macro while the form remains visible)?  My "workaround" is to have the "Apply" button call the macro directly, but this seems to breaking the encapsulation philosophy. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Module code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lBtn As Long
    Dim F As frmTest
    Set F = New frmTest
    F.Show
    lBtn = F.plBtn 'get clicked button
    Select Case lBtn
        Case 1
'           run macro1
        Case 2
'           run macro 2

'       etc, etc
    End Select

    Unload F 'done with form
End Sub
```

Form code:

```
Private Btn As Long
Public Property Get plBtn() As Long
    plBtn = Btn
End Property
Private Sub cmd1_Click()
    Btn = 1
    Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub cmd2_Click()
    Btn = 2
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just encapsulate the *numerical-id-to-macro-execution* logic into a function (replacing the use of a `Long` with an `Enum` for legibility):

```
Public Enum Macros
    MacroPrepareCake = 1
    MacroBakeCake
    MacroEatCake
End Enum

Public Sub RunMacro(macro As Macros)
    Select Case macro
        Case Macros.MacroPrepareCake
            '// code/call

        Case Macros.MacroBakeCake
            '// code/call

        Case Macros.MacroEatCake
            '// code/call

    End Select
End Sub
```

Then you can call `RunMacro` when the form is hidden or when Apply is clicked.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, it looks like we're calling an external macro from within form code - is that right?  I was hoping to avoid that, but maybe can't be avoided for an "Apply" scenario.